# PHP Create an Array or String based on condition

Tags: php

In the following code, I'm trying to create an array or a string based on `if type is true or false`. If `type` were `true`, then i need to create an array `else` I need to keep things as a string. I was trying as below, but it does not seem to work. Can you help?

```
<?php
$type = True;

if($type){
    $body = "body['body']"; //Start an array
} else {
    $body = 'body'; //Just a string
}

$body  = 'Hello'; //$body = the value from up there

print_r($body);
?>
```

**Expected Results:**

```
If type = true //Array
print_r($body);
Array ([body] => Hello)

If type = false //String
print_r($body); 
Hello
```

**Edit**
The content for the array or string is outside the if and comes after it. I need to start as a array or sting based on the type.

Comment: Whatever executes inside the `if - else statement` is pretty useless here .. because you are just overwriting it with `$body = 'Hello'` after the end of the `if-else`

Answer (score 3):

```
$type  = true;
$value = 'Hello';

if($type){
    $body['body'] = $value;
} else {
    $body = $value;
}

print_r($body);
```

Comment: The content for the array or string is outside the if.

Comment: I forgot to add, the content is set after the if. Which is why I posted that way.

Comment: `$value` needs to be assigned inside the if to ensure the type of `$body` is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$x = array('body'=>'Hello');
if($type){
    $body = $x;
} else {
    $body = 'body';
}
```

Comment: The content for the array or string is outside the if

Comment: check it now - this should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it on one line with shorthand if.

```
$body = ($type ? array('body'=>'Hello') : 'Hello');

var_dump($body);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$type  = true;
$value = 'Hello';

if($type){
    $body['body'] = $value;
} else {
    $body = $value;
}
if (is_array($body)) {
// content for array goes here
} else {
// content for string goes here
}
print_r($body);
```